# JSF request parameter encoding struggles

Tags: jsf, encoding, primefaces, utf-8, jboss7.x

On our web application we've got different forms which nearly all have a encoding problem on text input fields.
When the input includes special characters like a Ͳ the value in the Bean of the site shows a question mark. Umlauts and accents eg. get to the Bean without any problem.

The sent request tracked with firebug looks fine. The header shows an UTF-8 charset:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

And the request-parameter gets displayed right:

```
formInputPanel:comment    hello Ͳ
```

I googled a lot and most of the solutions I found tell me to implement a filter via the web.xml to set the right encoding for the request. The problem is when the filter is called the encoding is set right to UTF-8 but the parameter is already broken and shows `hello ?`

I also added following to lines to the system-properties of the JBoss without any results:

```
<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
```

This problem occurs on all pages except the login page. There the parameters get passed well to the Bean. The login page is implemented via a JSP-Page and a LoginServlet.

Maybe someone can give me a hint where else I can search for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved through adapting the `connection-url` of the database connection in the JBoss configuration to:

`jdbc:mysql://servername:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useUnicode=true`.

The encoding in the console output of the IDE wasn't UTF-8 encoded. So the request parameter were shown in the wrong encoding but the value was correct.